# Web Scraping 'Advice to management" not printing from Glassdoor

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and web scraping. I have trouble printing the "advice to management" part in the review from Glassdoor. Everything else is printing expect for "advice to management".

If you check below in the review we have 'advice to management' but in the output it's not getting scrapped with the rest of the datapoints.

Can anyone help me please?!! This is so important to me. It's the data I'm going to be using for my thesis.

I have tried this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 


def extract(pg): 
    headers = {'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.80 Safari/537.36'}
    url = f'https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Google-Engineering-Reviews-EI_IE9079.0,6_DEPT1007_IP{pg}.htm?sort.sortType=RD&sort.ascending=false&filter.iso3Language=eng'

    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')# this a soup function that retuen the whole html
    return soup

def transform(soup): #to get reviews
  

    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='gdReview')
    for item in divs:

        try:
          Title = item.find('h2', class_= 'mb-xxsm mt-0 css-93svrw el6ke055').text
        except:
          Title = None

        try:
          Rating = item.find('span', class_= 'ratingNumber mr-xsm').text.replace('<span class="ratingNumber mr-xsm">', '').strip()
        except:
          Rating = None    

        try:
          Employee_Situation= item.find('span', class_= 'pt-xsm pt-md-0 css-1qxtz39 eg4psks0').text.replace('<span class="pt-xsm pt-md-0 css-1qxtz39 eg4psks0">', '').strip()
        except:
          Employee_Situation = None  

        try:   
          Pros = item.find('span',  {'data-test':'pros'}).text.replace('<span data-test="pros">', '').strip()
        except:
          Pros = None

        try:  
          Cons = item.find('span',  {'data-test':'cons'}).text.replace('<span data-test="cons">', '')
        except:
          Cons: None

        try:    
          Advice_To_Management = item.find('span', {'data-test':'advice-management'}).text
        except: 
          Advice_To_Management = None

        try:
          Auhtor_Info = item.find('span', class_= 'common__EiReviewDetailsStyle__newUiJobLine').text.replace('<span class="common__EiReviewDetailsStyle__newUiJobLine"><span><span class="middle common__EiReviewDetailsStyle__newGrey">', '').strip()
        except:  
          Auhtor_Info = None


        Reviews = {
            'Title' : Title,
            'Rating': Rating,
            'Employee_Situation' : Employee_Situation,
            'Pros' : Pros,
            'Cons' : Cons,
            'Advice_To_Management' : Advice_To_Management,
            'Auhtor_Info' : Auhtor_Info,
        } 

        ReviewsList.append(Reviews) # to add reviews elements to our list 'ReviewList'
    return
   

ReviewsList = []


#loop into pages
for i in range(1,3,1):
    soup = extract( f'https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Google-Engineering-Reviews-EI_IE9079.0,6_DEPT1007_IP{i}.htm?sort.sortType=RD&sort.ascending=false&filter.iso3Language=eng')
    print(f' page {i}')
    
    transform(soup)
    
    print(len(ReviewsList))
    if not soup.find("data-test", class_ = "nextButton css-1hq9k8 e13qs2071"):
        pass
    else:
        break


df = pd.DataFrame(ReviewsList)

df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Title", "Rating", "Employee_Situation", "Pros", "Cons", "Auhtor_Info"], keep='first')

df2.to_csv('Google Reviews.csv')
print(len(df2))
```

Comment: When I go to one of the pages on my browser, I don't see any `span` elements with attribute `data-test="advice-management"` or any *"advice to management"* section at all...can you share a screenshot of the part of the page you're trying to scrape and also paste the outerHtml of the `span` element (or maybe it's parent element if it's not too large)?

Comment: I couldn't share a screenshot here. Try to open another review page you'll find in the review Pros, Cons, then Advice to management.
I have tried the parent element and it didn't work.

Comment: I see it now. I couldn't post earlier, but I've added my suggested solution/s now. hope they're helpful

Answer (score 0):

To get "Advice to management" you need to click on the link "Continue reading"

Therefore, one of the possible solutions could be for example `Selenium`:

```py
import csv
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def save_to_csv(data: list) -> None:
    with open(file='glassdoor.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow([*data])

def get_params(params: dict) -> str:
    return f"?{'&'.join([f'{k}={v}' for k, v in params.items()])}"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
service = Service(executable_path="path/to/your/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Google-Engineering-Reviews-EI_IE9079.0,6_DEPT1007.htm'
# sort options
params = {
    'sort.sortType': 'RD', 
    'sort.ascending': 'false', 
    'filter.iso3Language': 'eng'
    }
# cookies needed to prevent the login window from appearing
cookies = {
    "name": "at", 
    "value": "AQuAbmAwLKGMSj7gS4VKDrlQfUrJlSdHPS5T7ui1struL_UX8_FNmWke8iuqLwd9zGs0faZ29oqiGJyiePbR0cBUIU"\
        "Pk9V2h1dGnUG9RoU7COdbZqRl47h6dfhf9t31wRW9jiHIiIdCFre1fh_28W4tg0zg6yDwjMZ3u0PRDtS_cWKkljwrdI10xZt"\
        "Pk9V2h1dGnUG9RoU7CZ3u0PRDtS_cWKkljwrdI1OdbZqRl47hW4tg0zg6yDwjM6dfhf9t31wRW9jiHIiIdCFre1fh_380xZ-"\
        "HEfDZm6vHqOWOfb69DaVTECM22_D404WYg0B-WzLLfRFnVSsp8gFk6g0s-Iwc_mNAnKM_K_5c-dl6Lye5TQuprP1bt5SWbyB"\
        "UAxTL9VzpUdtLz8DL8L0b4se92IRRcq57SnZGF4egsw_b7xMDQyTSHiqk_6B-MrzBsJsYTbuzjPT_dnXDkq01SbtLmRYrqAi"\
        "lJ_ht6gzuGmq4QF-tp8T2VRA0smvYxmbeKlHYy-syz0h-vdGIGcFightEl_Lzs4hXXbu33mtl_NOjAALGXdfTHnZABt1OAx9"\
        "Pk9V2h1dGnUG9RoU7CW4tg0zg6yDwjMZ3u0PRDtS_cWKkljwrdI1OdbZqRl47h6dfhf9t31wRW9jiHIiIdCFre1fh_380xZt"\
        "ZcFqYZtSf9mXkC3OARMCpgeFh-zOh4O0ox2TwYMMUTU_hLgKtUY80Udt9GTDIpVRRxqUvEZ-FzTAcU8zMqAxY8SLp2VlX2zI"\
        "Pk9V2h1dGnUG9RoU7CW4tg0zg6yDwjMZ3u0PRDtS_cWKkljwqU1OdbZqRl47h6dfhf9t31wRW9jiHIiIdCFre1fh_380xZt"\
        "NU04W74RRsahOnblqDQWsbsq-gwQ"
    }

# page where data collection will stop
stop_page = 5

driver.get(f"{url}{get_params(params)}")
# add cookies and refresh the page
driver.add_cookie(cookies)
driver.refresh()

while True:
    # get all the reviews on the page
    reviews = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gdReview')))
    # click on all "Continue reading" links on the page
    driver.execute_script(
    """
    let cr = document.querySelectorAll('div.gdReview div.px-std>div.mb')
    Array.from(cr).forEach(e => {e.click()})
    """
    )
    for idx in range(len(reviews)):
        reviews = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gdReview')))
        rating = reviews[idx].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.ratingNumber').text
        employee_situation = reviews[idx].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gdReview>div>div>span').text
        title = reviews[idx].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.reviewLink').text
        auhtor_info = reviews[idx].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.middle:first-child').text
        pros = reviews[idx].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-test="pros"]').text
        cons = reviews[idx].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-test="cons"]').text
        try:
            advice = reviews[idx].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-test="advice-management"]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            advice = 'None'
        data = {
            'Title': title,
            'Rating': rating,
            'Employee_Situation': employee_situation,
            'Pros': pros.replace('\n', ' ').strip(),
            'Cons': cons.replace('\n', ' ').strip(),
            'Advice To Management': advice,
            'Auhtor Info': auhtor_info
        }
        save_to_csv(list(data.values()))
        print(data)
    
    if f"_IP{stop_page}" in driver.current_url:
        break
    driver.execute_script(
        """
        document.querySelector('button.nextButton').click()
        """
        )
    sleep(3)
    print(f"Current Page: {driver.current_url.split('_IP')[1].split('.htm')[0]}") 
driver.quit()
```

Output csv file `glassdoor.csv`:

```
Good,4.0,"Current Employee, more than 3 years",Flexible Positive Enthusiatic Fun Collaborative,Low leaves Low bonus LOVE LOVE LOVE,None,"Oct 27, 2022 - Software Eigineer"
Ni,5.0,Current Employee,Google join because best company,Google work friendly and lot of holidays,Excellent,"Oct 27, 2022 - Software Developer"
Software Engineer Intern,5.0,"Former Intern, less than 1 year",Good culture and good stipend,No cons as such in my experience.,None,"Oct 27, 2022 - Software Engineer Intern"
```

To avoid problems with the login window that appears and to avoid the need for authorization on the site, you can use cookies.

You only need:

```
{
     "name": "at",
     "value": "AQuAbmAwLKGMSj7gS4VKDr..."
}
```

You can get them for example by going to the `Application` tab in `DevTools` there you will see a list of `Cookies` in it select `www.glassdoor.com` then in the filter type 'at' and in the resulting list select `at` copy the value and paste it into the script.
[image: cookies]
Of course, you must do this while on the site and be logged in there.

And ofc, you can automate the login process using the capabilities of selenium, but in this case you don't need it.

Tested on `Python 3.9.10` and `Selenium 4.5.0`

**Update**:

If look at the source code of this site, you can see that the data we need is in `window.appCache` js object and can be obtained using, for example, `requests`, `BeautifulSoup`, and the `re` module.

Here is one possible solution how to extract data from this object:

```py
import re
import csv
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from typing import Generator, Tuple, List, Any


def get_page(num: int) -> str:
    return f'https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Google-Engineering-Reviews-EI_IE9079.0,6_DEPT1007_IP{num}.htm'

def save_to_csv(data: list) -> None:
    with open(file='glassdoor.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow([*data])

def get_job_title(job_titles: list, title_id: int) -> str:
    for title in job_titles:
        if title['jobTitleId'] == title_id:
            return title['jobTitle']

def get_employee_situation(review: dict) -> str:
    if review['isCurrentJob'] and review['employmentStatus'] == 'REGULAR':
        employee_situation = 'Current Employee'
    if not review['isCurrentJob'] and review['employmentStatus'] == 'REGULAR':
        employee_situation = 'Former Employee'
    if review['isCurrentJob'] and review['employmentStatus'] == 'INTERN':
        employee_situation = 'Current Intern'
    if not review['isCurrentJob'] and review['employmentStatus'] == 'INTERN':
        employee_situation = 'Former Intern'
    if review['isCurrentJob'] and review['employmentStatus'] == 'CONTRACT':
        employee_situation = 'Current Contractor'
    if not review['isCurrentJob'] and review['employmentStatus'] == 'CONTRACT':
        employee_situation = 'Former Contractor'
    if review['isCurrentJob'] and review['employmentStatus'] == 'PART_TIME':
        employee_situation = 'Current Employee - Part-time'
    if not review['isCurrentJob'] and review['employmentStatus'] == 'PART_TIME':
        employee_situation = 'Former Employee - Part-time'
    if review['isCurrentJob'] and review['employmentStatus'] == 'FREELANCE':
        employee_situation = 'Current Freelancer'
    if not review['isCurrentJob'] and review['employmentStatus'] == 'FREELANCE':
        employee_situation = 'Former Freelancer'
    return employee_situation

def get_data_by_key(data: dict, key: str) -> Generator[None, None, List[Any]]:
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            if k == key:
                yield v
            if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                yield from get_data_by_key(v, key)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for i in data:
            yield from get_data_by_key(i, key)

def json_validation(data: str) -> dict:
    script = [s.text for s in BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml").find_all("script") if "window.appCache" in s.text][0]

    script = re.sub(r'(\"urlRegexMatchers\")(([^@])+)(\"urlParams\")', '"urlRegexMatchers":{},"urlParams"', script)
    script = re.sub(r'(undefined)', '"undefined"', script) 
    script = re.sub(r'(}}}})', '}}}', script)
    script = re.sub(r'(}}};)', '}}}}', script)
    script = re.sub(r'(window\.appCache=)', '', script)
    try:
        return json.loads(script)
    except ValueError:
        script = script.replace('},"apolloState"', ',"apolloState"')
        return json.loads(script)

params = {
    'sort.sortType': 'RD',
    'sort.ascending': 'false',
    'filter.iso3Language': 'eng'
}
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    for i in range(1, 10):
        raw_data = session.get(get_page(i), params=params).text
        json_data = json_validation(raw_data)
        reviews = list(get_data_by_key(json_data, 'reviews'))[1]
        job_titles = list(get_data_by_key(json_data, 'jobTitlesByEmployer({\"employerId\":9079})'))

        for review in reviews:
            data = {
                'Title': review.get('summary'),
                'Rating': review.get('ratingOverall'),
                'Employee_Situation': get_employee_situation(review),
                'Pros': review.get('pros'),
                'Cons': review.get('cons'),
                'Advice To Management': review.get('advice', 'No data'),
                'Auhtor Info': get_job_title(job_titles[0], int(review['jobTitle']['__ref'].split(':')[1]))
            }
            save_to_csv(list(data.values()))
```

Output:

```
Software developer,5,Former Employee,learn new tech easily and get support,make our growth of individual profile,,Software Developer
Good,5,Former Employee,Amazing place to work at.,Too amazing for a normie,Let everyone be better,Software Engineer
Good,5,Former Employee,A good place to work. Good culture,"Busy, long hours some days",,Software Engineer
```

Tested on `Google Colab - [Python 3.7.15]`

Comment: Is there a way to solve this using BeautifulSoup package please?

Comment: @user19810494 with BeautifulSoup you can't press buttons, expand lists and etc. I updated answer and added another way to get data

Answer (score 0):

This method is quite similar to the second one added to [@Brze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10848420/brze)'s [posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74275374/6146136), but I'm structuring it in a way that fits into the code in your question.

Although it's not in the html, the advice is inside a JavaScript object within a `script` tag, so you should extract that at the **beginning** of you `transform(soup)` function, as well as the ID of each review in the loop so that you can match them up:

```py
def transform(soup): #to get reviews
    try:
        scriptIn = soup.find(
            lambda s: s.name == 'script' and 
            'window.appCache={' in s.text and 
            '"apolloState"' in s.text
        ).text # get the contents of script tag (JavaScript)

        #### apolloJson = .... #### (see next section) ####

        empRevs = [
            v['reviews'] for k, v in apolloJson['ROOT_QUERY'].items() 
            if 'employerReviews' in k and 'reviews' in v
        ][0]
    except:
        empRevs = []
  

    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='gdReview')
    for item in divs: 
        try:
          revId = int(item.find_parent('li').get('id').replace('empReview_', ''))
        except:
          revId = None

        #### Title, Rating, Employee_Situation, Pros, Cons = ... ####

        try:    
          Advice_To_Management = [
              r['advice'] for r in empRevs if r['reviewId'] == revId
          ][0]
        except: 
          Advice_To_Management = None

        #### Auhtor_Info = ... ####
        #### Reviews = {...}  ####
        #### ReviewsList.append(Reviews) ####
    return
```

---

There are two ways to get the `apolloJson` variable that I skipped defining; the simpler way would be but just splitting the string

```py
# import json

        apolloJson = json.loads(',"apolloState":'.join(
            scriptIn.strip().split(',"apolloState":')[1:]
        )[:-2])
```

However, that assumes that `apolloState` will always be the last item inside the last (or only) object in the script, so I think it will be safer to use a js parser like `slimit`

```py
# import json
# import slimit
# from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor


        tree = slimit.parser.Parser().parse(scriptIn)
        treeDesc = []
        apolloJson = '{}'

        for n in nodevisitor.visit(tree): 
            if n.children()[0].left.to_ecma() == 'window.appCache':
                treeDesc = n.children()[0].right.children() 
                break

        for c in treeDesc:
            if c.left.to_ecma() == '"apolloState"': 
                apolloJson = c.right.to_ecma()
                break

        apolloJson = json.loads(apolloJson)
```

[I don't know if `slimit` has any native functions that work like `find` in `bs4`, so I had to use loops to search....]